# Fastest way to allocate a large string in Go?

Tags: go

I need to create a string in Go that is 1048577 characters (1MB + 1 byte). The content of the string is totally unimportant. Is there a way to allocate this directly without concatenating or using buffers?

Also, it's worth noting that the value of string will not change. It's for a unit test to verify that strings that are too long will return an error.

Comment: "Unit testing" and "fastest way" sound contradictory. You should always aim for simplicity over performance in unit testing. Performance does not matter that much in tests as it does in production code. What you suggested in your answer is perfectly fine for unit tests.

Answer (score 14):

Use [strings.Builder](https://godoc.org/strings#Builder) to allocate a string without using extra buffers.

```
var b strings.Builder
b.Grow(1048577)
for i := 0; i < 1048577; i++ {
  b.WriteByte(0)
}
s := b.String()
```

The call to the [Grow](https://godoc.org/strings#Builder.Grow) method allocates a slice with capacity 1048577. The WriteByte calls fill the slice to capacity.  The [String()](https://godoc.org/strings#Builder.String) method uses [unsafe](https://godoc.org/unsafe) to convert that slice to a string.

The cost of the loop can be reduced by writing chunks of N bytes at a time and filling single bytes at the end.

If you are not opposed to using the unsafe package, then use this:

```
p := make([]byte, 1048577)
s := *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&p))
```

If you are asking about how to do this with the simplest code, then use the following:

```
s := string(make([]byte, 1048577)
```

This approach does not meet the requirements set forth in the question. It uses an extra buffer instead of allocating the string directly.

Comment: Do I need the loop at all? Do I need to set the last byte to zero?

Comment: The only way to extend the length of the builder is to append data with Write, WriteByte, WriteRune or  WriteString.  There's no SetLength(int) or similar call.

Answer (score 5):

I ended up using this:

```
string(make([]byte, 1048577))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/afPukPc1Esr

Comment: This exact method was mentioned by ThunderCat originally, why not just accept his answer?

Comment: I provided this answer when @thundercat only had the first code sample

Answer (score 0):

To create large strings, I did 3 procedures:

**BStrAlloc** you specify the maximum size. It is important to estimate the size and preferably enter more. The **BStrAdd** function is used to add strings.
At the end, **BStrEnd** returns the resulting string.
**BStrTest** shows applications where just adding to the string usually takes almost **55 seconds**. Using BStr it takes only **38 milliseconds**.

```
//------------- fast string add  (for big strings)-----------------------

func BStrAlloc(pStr string, pMaxLen int) ([]byte, int) { //Alloc| Add,Add...| End
    var b []byte
    if len(pStr) > pMaxLen || pMaxLen < 1 {
        return b, -1
    }
    b = make([]byte, pMaxLen, pMaxLen)
    reader := strings.NewReader(pStr)
    for i := 0; i < len(pStr); i++ {
        char, _ := reader.ReadByte()
        b[i] = char
    }
    reader = nil
    return b, len(pStr)
}

func BStrAdd(b []byte, pLen int, pAddStr string) ([]byte, int) { //Alloc| Add,Add...| End
    if len(pAddStr)+pLen > cap(b) {
        return b, pLen
    }
    reader := strings.NewReader(pAddStr)
    for i := pLen; i < pLen+len(pAddStr); i++ {
        char, _ := reader.ReadByte()
        b[i] = char
    }
    reader = nil //save memory
    return b, pLen + len(pAddStr)
}

func BStrEnd(b []byte, pLen int) string { //Alloc| Add,Add...| End
    t := string(b[0:pLen])
    b = nil //save memory
    return t
}

func BStrTest() {
    s := "" 
    cnt := 500000
    start1 := StartDuration()
    for i := 0; i < cnt; i++ {
        s += "ABCD"
    }
    fmt.Println("String add:" + StopDuration(start1) + " len:" + fmt.Sprint(len(s)) + " " + Sub(s, 0, 100)) 
    //duration: 00:54.084

    s = "" 
    start2 := StartDuration()
    b, bLen := BStrAlloc(s, 4*cnt+1000) //Alloc| Add,Add...| End
    if bLen > -1 {
        for i := 0; i < cnt; i++ {
            b, bLen = BStrAdd(b, bLen, "ABCD")
        }
    }
    s = BStrEnd(b, bLen)
    fmt.Println("BStrAdd:" + StopDuration(start2) + " len:" + fmt.Sprint(len(s)) + " " + Sub(s, 0, 100)) 
    // duration: 00:00.038
}
```